# Read JSON with Current Date and get key value using Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to get the count from `JSON` response which has current date in the key.

`Json` Response:

```
[
  {
    "type": {
      "id": "mobile",
      "name": "mobile",
      "description": "",
      "total_count": 0
    },
    "counts": [
      {
        "date": "2018-09-06",
        "timestamp": 1536192000000,
        "count": 20
      },
      {
        "date": "2018-09-07",
        "timestamp": 1536278400000,
        "count": 10
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "type": {
      "id": "lap",
      "name": "lap",
      "description": "",
      "total_count": 0
    },
    "counts": [
      {
        "date": "2018-09-06",
        "timestamp": 1536192000000,
        "count": 19
      },
      {
        "date": "2018-09-07",
        "timestamp": 1536278400000,
        "count": 20
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

My New try as per vikscool code:

```
var json_count = JSON.parse(getcounts);
var curDate = getCurrentDate();
var mobilcount = () => json_count.map(ct => {
  const count = ct.counts;
  const getDate = count.find(dt => dt.date === curDate);
  window.alert('count is ', getDate.count);
  return {getDate};
});
mobilcount();

function getCurrentDate () {
  var nowDate = new Date();
  var month = (nowDate.getMonth() + 1).toString().length == 1
    ? '0' + (nowDate.getMonth() + 1)
    : (nowDate.getMonth() + 1);

  var day = nowDate.getDate().toString().length == 1
    ? '0' + nowDate.getDate()
    : +nowDate.getDate();

  return nowDate.getFullYear() + '-' + month + '-' + day;
}
```

output: "count is "

but there is no count printed from json.

Is there any solution in `Javascript` I can get the current date and get the counts.

I need to get the *count as 10 in mobilcount*.

Comment: is this the complete `JSON` response object if yes then I am not able to see the array named `values` in it.

Comment: The JSON blob is invalid and there's no `values` property anywhere to be found.

Comment: @vikscool,@Robby, I am sorry , I meant key value in the sense to count: Integer(some int).I need to fetch the count with respect to current date

Comment: @dow your updated code is almost correct, just change your `window.alert()` the `alert()` only takes 1 parameter so just change your code to either concatenate the string with value or only pass the value to it as `window.alert("count is "+getDate.count);`

Comment: @vikscoll, That was a great catch, I really don't know that alert takes one parameter. learned now. Thanks!!. One more doubt, If I want to get the count based on the Id from the JSON. what can be done? 
I am trying something like:
     var mobilcount=json_count.map(ct =>{
      const id  = ct.type.id['mobile'];                                        
      const count = ct.counts;       
      const getDate = count.find(dt => dt.date === curDate);
      window.alert("count is " +id.getDate.count);
but i am getting error as id is undefined.
how can i catch id of lap,mobile,tablet count

Comment: @dow the `ct.type.id['mobile']` is not correct as the square `[]` takes either the `index` or the name of the `key`, not the `value`. hence you are getting an error as  **id is not defined**. So, change it to `const id = ct["type"]["id"];` and that should work.

Comment: @dow always have in mind that  JSON is a `key-value` based object. So, you can access its values via its `keys` only.

Comment: @vikscool, I tried as you said :const id=  ct["type"]["id"]."mobile";  or ct["type"]["id"]["mobile"];
but i am gettting error while i do alert("count" +id.getDate.count);
getting -> missing id after operator.

Comment: Don't put the ID (mobile) in the syntax just call it without it as `const id = ct['type']['id'] ;`there is no key present in the JSON as mobile/lap/tablet these are values.

Comment: @vikscool, How can i get the count based on values then? if mobile is value in ID i need to get the count based on the values in ID ?can you please just any solution

Comment: @dow I have updated my answer please check it.

Comment: @vikscool, Really a good lesson learnt from you and StackOverflow. thank you very much vikscool , you made me understand and code. your explanation of code really helps. I got a proper solution for my programme finally.

Comment: @dow you are welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the `dates` are stored in the `JSON Array key` named as the `counts` of the first object of the `json_count` you can not fetch it using:

```
var instance_count=json_count[0].values[2].count;
```

As your json object does not have any key named as `values`.

What you have to do is first access the `counts` key then get the particular object from it which contains the **particular**(*current date as in your case*) and then get the counts from it.

Below is a sample code to get the particular date's count:

```js
//assuming this is the Json response you are getting as complete JSON response is not provided by the OP.

var getcounts = `[{"type":{"id":"mobile","name":"mobile","description":"","total_count":0},"counts":[{"date":"2018-09-05","timestamp":1533686400000,"count":0},{"date":"2018-09-06","timestamp":1533772800000,"count":8}]}]`;
//parsing the given json String 
var json_count = JSON.parse(getcounts);


function getCountForCurrentDate() {
  var curDate = getCurrentDate(); //for which the data is to be fetched and making in format of the dates in JSON as yyyy-mm-dd

  //finding the particular object that contains the current date
  var searchedObj = json_count[0]['counts'].find(f => f['date'] == curDate);
  if(searchedObj!==undefined)
     console.log('count is', searchedObj['count']);
}


function getCurrentDate() {
  var nowDate = new Date();
  var month = (nowDate.getMonth() + 1).toString().length == 1 ? '0' + (nowDate.getMonth() + 1) : (nowDate.getMonth() + 1);
  var day = nowDate.getDate().toString().length == 1 ? '0' + nowDate.getDate() : +nowDate.getDate();
  return nowDate.getFullYear() + '-' + month + '-' + day;
}

getCountForCurrentDate();
```

Here in the snippet above, i have created two functions `getCurrentDate()` to get the current date in the format it is stored in `JSON` response and `getCountForCurrentDate()` to get the `count` from the `json_count` variable.

> **Update 1** as per the new requirement is given by **OP**

The given `JSON` object is as follows:

```
var json_count = [
  {
    type: {
      id: "mobile",
      name: "mobile",
      description: "",
      total_count: 0
    },
    counts: [
      {
        date: "2018-09-06",
        timestamp: 1536192000000,
        count: 20
      },
      {
        date: "2018-09-07",
        timestamp: 1536278400000,
        count: 10
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    type: {
      id: "lap",
      name: "lap",
      description: "",
      total_count: 0
    },
    counts: [
      {
        date: "2018-09-06",
        timestamp: 1536192000000,
        count: 19
      },
      {
        date: "2018-09-07",
        timestamp: 1536278400000,
        count: 20
      }
    ]
  }
];
```

And now as the object has two entities one for `mobile` and another for `lap` we can fetch the particular values as:

```
var mobile = json_count.find(f=>f['type']['id']=='mobile');//comparing the value present in the json object at location type.id to 'mobile' (change it to 'lap' or anything that is present in the id of the object).
```

and now to get the count for it we do as:

```
var mobile_count = mobile.counts.find(f=>f['date']=='2018-09-07');//replace the static date with the date you want to fetch the count from
```

and then access the `count` as:

```
console.log(mobile_count.count);
//output:10
```

Comment: This code is really great, But i am not sure why i am getting undefined otuput. it is not going inside the json.

Comment: could you please provide your actual json `response` or can you put a breakpoint inside `getCountForCurrentDate()` and check what is the value of `searchedObj`.

Comment: I have edited the Question with your try and provided JSON.can you please help me here. why i am not getting the count